# use UIScrollView to show CarouselImagesView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a UIScrollView can show a set of pages and have "carousel" effect, what I want is snap to an image after the user finishes dragging.Should I add some other func such like `scrollViewDidEndDragging` to observe user's action??? Thank you.

**Code**

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        timer?.invalidate()

        scrolled(scrollView: scrollView)
    }

 private func scrolled(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        guard let imageUrls = self.imageUrls else {
            return
        }

        if imageUrls.count < 1 {
            return
        }
.
        if abs(lastContentOffset - scrollView.contentOffset.x) < 50 {
            return
        }

        if lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x {
            if currentPageIndex == 0 {
                currentPageIndex = imageUrls.count - 1
            } else {
                currentPageIndex -= 1
            }
        } else {
            if currentPageIndex < imageUrls.count - 1 {
                currentPageIndex += 1
            } else {
                currentPageIndex = 0
            }
        }

        layoutImages()

        self.delegate?.didChangePage(currentPageIndex)
    }
```

Comment: Please don't ask a question with *"like Airbnb"* ... that doesn't make any sense to someone who doesn't use that app. Try to do a better job describing your goal. You have a set of images? And you want to show them scrollable, where each image is the width of the scroll view? And you want to snap to an image after the user finishes dragging? And you want a "carousel" effect, where scrolling past the end of the image list resumes back at the beginning of the list?

Comment: @DonMag Exactly that's what I want, thank you for your recommendation

Comment: I'd suggest you search for `carousel image slideshow swift` ... lots of results including example apps, tutorials, discussions, etc. Your question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

First of all scroll view are not reliable from memory point of view, in future if there are lots of images loaded dynamically your app may end up in memory flood situation and may crash.

Better use views like collection view, stack view or table view for cell reusability and it will also solve dragging problem.

Comment: thank you for advice. I have searched a lot examples that almost do it with collection view.

Comment: @KPK - This does not answer the question so it should be a comment...